# Making a new major version of a package

Tags: managed-package

We have a released package version 1.x we are trying to make 2.0.  How do we update and put new code into the packaging org.

We are using an ANT deploy from a prePackaging org. Right now it's not letting us overwrite the files because they are part of a managed package.
Obviously there are updates to existing files, new files, and we need to remove some files.

How can we do this and create a 2.0 package? Do we have to make a Beta with the existing 1.x files first?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying delete. Once a managed package is released, most of the components are locked. If you want to remove things like fields, you can open a ticket with SF support to allow component deletion. However, if you try to remove apex this will not work. In order to create a package with version 2.0 you can do this when packaging.